# Never receiving "@odata.nextLink" in Azure Active Directory Graph API Delta call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get the differences in the groups of my Azure Active Directory with C#. I need to know when users are deleted or added. I have used the following URL; [tutorial from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

I am authorized for this Azure AD and I receive the changes, but I should also receive a "@odata.nextLink" or "@odata.deltaLink". This can be used for the next time you will retrieve the changes.

Can someone help me? It's probably something simple...

Below you can find my code;

```
`string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
 var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/v2.0")
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async (requestMessage) => {
            var authResult = await confidentialClient
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Bearer",
            authResult.AccessToken
            );
        })
    );

var delta = await graphServiceClient.Groups
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .Select("displayName,description,members")
    .GetAsync();

return Ok(delta);
```

This is what the response looks like; [image]

Comment: I can see the members@delta property is included in the screenshot you added , are you saying that you are able to see the members@delta in graph explorer but not in graph SDKs, am i correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. When I do the manual GET request via https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer it does return the "@odata.nextLink" prop. I don't receive it via the SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a little different. Here's my test.

When I test via http request, it has `"@odata.context` and `@odata.nextLink"`:

[image]

When I visit the url provided by `nextLink`, I will get `deltaLink`:

[image]

Then going to the SDK, I can't get `nextLink` in `AdditionalData`, but I can get the next page request in `NextPageRequest` variable:

[image]

I can get `deltaLink` when there's no response in AdditionalData:

[image]

So I'm afraid you can follow my code snippet to test again:

```
var delta = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Delta().Request().GetAsync();

            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("$skiptoken", delta.NextPageRequest.QueryOptions[0].Value)
            };

            var delta2 = await _graphServiceClient.Users
                .Delta()
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .GetAsync();
```

I also test the client credential flow, it has the same behavior:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you TinyWang & @user2250152. I can move on again!

Comment: Oh thank you, and I reviewed the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#response), I found that the   `deltaLink` should appear when there's no nextpage content, and any other time there should be a `nextLink ` in the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can read `@odata.nextLink` and `@odata.deltaLink` form `AdditionalData` property

```
delta.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.deltaLink", out var deltaLink)
delta.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.nextLink ", out var nextLink)
```

Just a tip:

When you call

```
var deltaPage = await graphServiceClient.Groups
    .Delta().Request().Select("displayName,description,members")
    .GetAsync();
```

the type of the result is `IGroupDeltaCollectionPage` and you can iterate all pages to get all groups in the code

```
var deltaPage = await graphServiceClient.Groups
    .Delta().Request().Select("displayName,description,members")
    .GetAsync();

deltaPage.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.deltaLink", out var deltaLink)

var groups = new List<Group>();

groups.AddRange(deltaPage.CurrentPage);
while (deltaPage.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    deltaPage = await deltaPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    groups.AddRange(deltaPage.CurrentPage);
}
```

Comment: `await deltaPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();` amazing, I tried to find it, but I only found `.Request(queryOptions)`